# Ionic - A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I need to store cookies for my http requests in my app so I set `$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;`

However, upon setting this I got an error when doing http requeust:

```
A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I believe this error will not show on devices but I want to debug the app using my pc's web browser. I tried to configure my config.xml and setting access origin to localhost:8100 but it doesn't work either.

I'm also using Chrome's Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: * but no luck too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct, when running your ionic app on a mobile device as an app, or in the emulator the CORS restrictions do not apply.

You can disable these restrictions in Google Chrome with the `--disable-web-security` flag. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6083677

This flag does reduce your browsers security so I would only keep it disabled while developing your application and relaunch chrome without the flag before doing any other web browsing.

Comment: Try launching chrome with web security disabled? See  http://stackoverflow.com/a/6083677 for details on how to do it.

Comment: Did you completely close Chrome before trying to launch it with the flag? You should have also gotten a yellow warning bar in chrome on launch - which you can dismiss - letting you know web security is disabled.

Comment: It works now, it needed ALL chrome instances to be closed before applying the flag. Thanks!